# Efficiently check if a File object is a valid Image

Tags: performance-tuning, image, files-and-directories

I have a directory of images that might not have downloaded, and need to delete the duds.

This is too slow: `Import /* ImageQ /@ fileNames`

In bash, I use the `file` command to inspect the metadata of an image file's header, but `ImageQ` only works on in-memory images not paths or `File` objects.

*Is there some way to do this efficiently, without importing them?  There's a function for this I forgot.*

**Update:**

`FileFormat` has a problem - it checks all known filetypes! e.g. you can't just check if the file is one of a list `{"JPEG","PNG","TIFF"}`.

Comment: If you don't want to import them, then all you have is the file's extension, right? Or what other property would you like to check *without looking inside the file*?

Comment: Make an image called "myfile.jpg" but then remove the extension. `FileFormat["myfile"]` will still return JPEG. Presumably it inspects the file's [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) FFD8FF and determines it looks like a JPEG. Of course it could be a coincidence or a corrupt file. Only parsing the headers would determine it was a valid JPEG file which is tantamount to Import-ing it

Comment: @flinty Yup `FileFormat` was the symbol I was forgetting, thanks!

Comment: What is the problem in the update? Couldn't you just check `MemberQ[{"JPEG", "PNG", "TIFF"}, FileFormat[f]]` or is it too slow?

Comment: FileFormat checks all these: is a pdf, is it HTML, is it bson... That's inefficient

Comment: I'm very much not convinced that you can check that a potentially partially downloaded file is a valid image without loading it in its entirety -- the file type is usually determined by extremely early header information, but I'd think checking the correctness of the file (including just validity as some kind of image) would requiring checking at least some kind of checksum or expected size value.

Comment: @eyorble you're right but heuristics can get most of them

Comment: @M.R. why is it inefficient - have you timed it? Given how many file types there are, it was very quick with my previous example. You must think it's checking them linearly but it could use a suffix tree, nested hash table, or another efficient data structure for quick recognition of the file's magic number. Of course, whether it does that or not is only known by wolfram. I doubt it just runs through a giant list.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps you already:

Lets take the filenames as a provided list as you suggest.

```
fileNames = {} (*your list here*)
```

First, lets time the code you provided:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Import /* ImageQ /@ fileNames]
```

> {0.204095, {True, True, True, True}}

Speed up by a factor of 2 gives this code:

```
AbsoluteTiming[MemberQ[Import[#, "Elements"], "Image"] & /@ fileNames]
```

> {0.0822613, {True, True, True, True}}

Speed up by a factor of 20 seems to give this:

```
Extensions = {‰PNG, ‰JPG} (*or other extensions*)
AbsoluteTiming[MemberQ[Extensions, First@ReadList[#, Expression, 1]] & /@ fileNames]
```

> {0.00788099, {True, True, True, True}}

Note that the last code also works if you delete the .png extension from the file name. So "image.png" and "image" give both `True`.